# Linear probing Hash Table not inserting all elements

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

Been trying to hammer down hash functions and implementing a hash table with linear probing and quadratic probing, however I am running into an issue where not all data values are being inserted. I am starting with a csv of 10,0000 integers <100,000 and reading them into an array. From that I am inserting 100 values at a time and recording how long that takes.

When printing out the HashTable (Or at least the bottom 1000 nodes), i noticed there was quite a lot of NULL values, and it turns out there are 177 NULL values when using a certain dataset, and around 700 when using another. I am really not sure where I am going wrong as I have looked at essentially every implementation of a hash table with linear probing and they still don't fully work.

I am fairly confident in the parsing of the CSV in that when going through the array in testing, I did not see any bogus values nor empty slots or values in wrong slots.

I will include a sample of the data I am using along with the files, any help or tips is greatly appreciated as it seems I cannot wrap my head around this.

```
17713,36933,34262,19985,29293,74317,79460,3356,18949,70018,56659,47601,2754,59469,22496,25331,58588,4903,65300,48561,8484,61670,79679,50514,40216,64252,3911,57275,7674,48557,35502,44792,
```

```
#ifndef HASHLINEAR_HPP
#define HASHLINEAR_HPP

struct node{
    
    int key;
    
};

class HashLinear{
    node** table;
    int tableSize;
    int numCollisions = 0;

    public:
        HashLinear(int bsize);
        void insert(int key);
        unsigned int hashFunction(int key);
        int search(int key);

        int getCollisions();
        void printTable();
};


#endif
```

```
#include "hashlinear.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HashLinear::HashLinear(int bsize){
    this->tableSize = bsize;
    table = new node*[tableSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++){
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
}

int HashLinear::getCollisions(){
    return numCollisions;
}

unsigned int HashLinear::hashFunction(int key){
    return key % tableSize;
}

// void HashLinear::insert(int key){ //Another method I tried using to insert
//     node* newNode = new node;
//     newNode->key = key;
//     int index = hashFunction(key);
//     int func = 1;
//     while(table[index] != NULL && table[index]->key != key){
//         numCollisions++;
//         index = (index + func) % tableSize;
//         func++;
//     }
//     table[index] = newNode;
    
// }
void HashLinear::insert(int key){
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->key = key;
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    int func = 1;
    if(table[index] == NULL){
        table[index] = newNode;
        //cout << "Inserted" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else{
        numCollisions++;
        index = (index + func) % tableSize;
        while(table[index] != NULL and table[index]->key != key){
            func++;
            index = (index + func) % tableSize;
        }
        if(table[index] == NULL){
            table[index] = newNode;
        }
    }
    
    
}



int HashLinear::search(int key){
    int value = hashFunction(key);

    int num = 0;

    while(table[value] != NULL){
        num = 0;
        if(num++ > tableSize){
            break;
        }

        if(table[value]->key == key){
            return value;
        }
        value++;
        value %= tableSize;
    }
    return -1;
}

void HashLinear::printTable(){
    int nullCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++){
        cout << i << " || ";
        if(table[i] == NULL){
            cout << "NULL" << endl;
            nullCount++;
        }
        else{
            cout << table[i]->key << endl;
        }
        
    }
    cout << "Null Count: " << nullCount << endl;
}
```

```
#include "hashlinear.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



int main(){
    //******Read in data******//
    int testData[10000];
    float insertTime[100];
    float searchTime[100];
    int index = 0;
    string line, temp, word;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("dataSetA-updatedhashlinear.csv");
    if(inputFile.fail()){
        std::cout << "Could not open data." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        while(inputFile >> temp){
            getline(inputFile, temp);
            stringstream inStream(temp);
            while(getline(inStream, word, ',')){
                if(word == ""){
                    index++;
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    testData[index] = stoi(word);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
    //******Read in data******//

    //cout << "Printing random data in range of 0 ~ 10: " << testData[rand() % 10 + 0] << endl;

    //******Insert/Search data in Linked List******//
    HashLinear table(10009);
    int hashIndex = 0;
    int insertTimeIndex = 0;
    int searchTimeIndex = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int upperIndex = 99;
    while(hashIndex < 10000 && upperIndex < 10000){
        //Block for 100 insertions
        auto insertionStart = chrono::steady_clock::now();//Insert time start
        for(int i = hashIndex; i < upperIndex; i++){ //Keep track of current index as well as an upper index to control amount of inserts
            table.insert(testData[i]);
            hashIndex++;
            
        }
        auto insertionEnd = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        insertTime[insertTimeIndex] = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(insertionEnd - insertionStart).count() / 100.0;//Insert time end
        insertTimeIndex++;

        //Block for 100 insertions
        //Block for 100 searches
        num = 0;
        auto searchStart = chrono::steady_clock::now();//Search time start
        while(num < 100){ //Do 100 random searches from 0 index to upperindex
            srand((unsigned)time(0));
            int searchNode = table.search(testData[rand() % upperIndex + 0]);
            num++;
        }
        auto searchEnd = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        searchTime[searchTimeIndex] = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(searchEnd - searchStart).count() / 100.0;//Search time end
        searchTimeIndex++;
        //Block for 100 searches
        
        upperIndex += 100;
        
    }
    //******Insert/Search data in Linked List******//

    //******TESTING******//
    //table.printTable();
    std::cout << "Search time: " << searchTime[20] << endl;
    std::cout << "Insert time: " << insertTime[20] << endl;
    std::cout << "Collisons: " << table.getCollisions() << endl;
    int testIndex = table.search(34262);
    std::cout << "Index of 34262: " << testIndex << endl;
    //******TESTING******//
}
```

Comment: `while(inputFile >> temp)` reads a space-delimited token and never uses it. You're throwing out data. Looks like `while(getline(inputFile, temp)){` is more in line with what you are after. Is this your bug? Effed if I know. I recommend manufacturing a [mre] to help isolate the bug, then squish the bug once it's isolated.

Comment: @user4581301 I dont believe that is the bug as when I changed it to that I get the same data, and same number of NULL values in the hash table. The CSV I'm reading is one single line so all of that data going into testData[] should be correct

Comment: You have uninitialized `testData` entries when you have empty `word`s when reading in data. `insert` can sometimes insert duplicate records (if the initial table entry has a node with that value) , other times it won't (if there is a collision and the existing node was inserted after a collision). `search` is linear while the collision resolution in `insert` uses an increasing step size.

Comment: Learn to write a unit tests for testing separate part of your code (Split file IO to parts and us istream as argument type, then we can test it with in-memory string stream)